# If a browser can modify local files, won't that create big security hazard?

Tags: security, browser

Some Youtube download plugin for Firefox will actually download the video track and sound track separately (as 2 separate files), and then upon finish, it will merge the 2 files into 1 file.

So it looks like a modern browser can read, modify, and create local files? Is that is true, won't that be a big security hazard?

Comment: Yes it's true; But it's always been true;

Comment: Extensions & plugins have a different security model than normal web pages.

Comment: @Ramhound ... since the age of _Lynx_. Merry Xmas to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're equating two very different things:

1) The ability to read from and write to files on the local hard disk in a specific, controlled location and using software that does not come from a web page.

2) The ability to read from and write to arbitrary files anywhere on the local hard disk as directed by a web page that someone browses to.

What you are seeing is 1. What you should be concerned about is 2.

Every browser has to read from and write to local files. Every browser takes instructions from web pages. Every browser has logic that the web pages cannot modify that controls what the web page is and is not allowed to do.

Comment: so when Firefox downloads 2 files, and merge them into 1 file... those 3 files are the "contained" files that can be modified, but not any other files, you are saying.  Just that what if some plugin merge the 2 files and create 1 file, and then also create `AdobeFlashInstall.dmg` which is fake, and the user didn't take notice of this new file? If a webpage download additional files to your computer, at least your notice a download started and some browser warn you too. In the "created file" case, it is "silently created".

Comment: Who says the page gets to choose the name of the file?

Comment: @太極者無極而生, _In the "created file" case, it is "silently created"_ you didn't mention that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

#### I. So it looks like a modern browser can read, modify, and create local files?

For what I remember it was always been so, since the *age* of [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/) <sup>[[1](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/),[1b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))]</sup> and [mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser))<sup>[[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(web_browser))]</sup>.

The browser saves and modifies files under a specific location (cache, temporary files...) and allows the user to save a file in other locations, asking for a specific place or saving in the default (or set) path.

**Note: the user transfers the control of the place where to save and modify files to the browser. The operating system can still avoid it.**

#### II. Is that is true, won't that be a big security hazard?

Until there is not an exploit it is *normally* safe, until the browser security is not compromised (malware, virus, bugs, malicious code...). The browser codes are normally intensively checked. Some browsers are open source and this allows you to take your own view.

**BUT** In the moment you install such kind of *plug-in*, you are **transferring the control** on the I/O file operations (read, write, modify, delete...) that you gave to the browser **to the plug-in**  itself.

So you add an hazard inversely proportional to the trustful of the installed *plug-in*.
If the plug-in is safe no hazard, if not you add a risk...